# Make C++ preprocessor add a character at the end of each line

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, compile-time

I am implementing some compile-time check which should base on a CSV file and I am trying to load it a bit hacky way:

```
constexpr std::variant<int, const char*> test[] = {
#include "data.csv"
};
```

where "data.csv" is:

```
  "a","b","c"
  1,"xyz",1
  2,"abc",0
  3,"def",1
```

Obviously, there is a problem with the lack of commas at the end of each line. Is there a way to add a comma with C++ (or even Boost) preprocessor at the end of each line?

I know I could add some token at the end of each line and then replace it with `#define`, but I would like to avoid it for the sake of clarity. Can one replace a `\n` character with `#define`?

Comment: Create a pre-build step that creates a (temporary) file using the correct format which can then be included?

Comment: By the way, what is the data supposed to represent? Is each line a single *record* (structure) of data? Then an array of variants doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: Indeed, a pre-build step could be a solution, I will try that if there is no other option.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes each row is a single record. Why doesn't it make sense? Having the aray element as a structure of int/char*/int would be also possible, but would require additional parsing (adding curly braces). Also, I would have to treat differently the first line. Am I missing something?

Comment: An array of structures would make more sense. It would make much of your code much easier to handle, make it more readable, understandable, and therefore more maintainable. It would then also be possible to add behavior (member functions) if needed.

Comment: `I know I could add some token at the end of each line and then replace it,` ? Just add a comma then.............

Comment: Notice the latter part of the sentence ", but I would like to avoid it for the sake of clarity.". I am aware I can resort to uglier solutions, but I wanted to check if there is something more elegant I could do.

Comment: Could be possible, but with major limitations. You need at least N boilerplate macros to support up to N lines of CSV (so large files can't be reasonably processed; how many lines does yours have?), and the first column has to have no quotes (header doesn't count), and the set of possible values in the first column has to be small (you need one boilerplate macro for every possible value). If all those conditions are met, I could try to go for an answer. Also: is C++20 available?

Comment: Perhaps you can hack something together with multiline string literals and `constexpr` functions? With the whole file `data.csv` as single string. The start and end of the string tokens would have to be inside `data.csv`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , it could grow up to a few hundred lines and the first column values can go up to 2^16, so I am afraid this is not a solution. Also, I am stuck with C++17 for now.

Comment: @Sebastian Indeed, one could write a CSV string parser. There are actually at least two i can find on github as well, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: It's impossible then (a few hundred macros for lines is ok, but 2^16 macros is not viable). As for string literals, I don't think you can `#include` something into one. You'd have to open it at runtime, or use compiler-specific methods of embedding data into an executable.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to add a comma with C++ (or even Boost) preprocessor at the end of each line?

Yes, create a macro:

```
#define ADD_COMMA(...)  __VA_ARGS__ ,
```

Then change each line of the file to:

```
  ADD_COMMA("a","b","c")
  ADD_COMMA(1,"xyz",1)
  ADD_COMMA(2,"abc",0)
  ADD_COMMA(3,"def",1)
```

If by "is there a way to add a comma" you mean reading the file line by line in preprocessor and calling some macro on each line, then no, that is not possible. Such functionality is broadly out-of-scope for a C preprocessor.

BTW your problem looks oddly trivial - just add a comma on the end of each line to the file with an external tool.

Comment: But then the CSV file becomes invalid, so I could do it only as a pre-build step just for the sake of compile-time checks, as @some-programmer-dude suggested. In such case I can just directly add a comma at this step.

Comment: Can't there be an empty column in a CSV file? If not, put a token after the final comma, which you can remove with the preprocessor. :-)

Comment: an empty column! that's actually quite neat and still keeps the CSV file valid, thanks.